# General Topology: Is there a surjective continuous or homeomorphism from $(0,1)^{\omega}$ in uniform Topology to $R^{\omega}$ in uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology

We know there exists a surjective continuous function from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I was wondering is it true in $(0,1)^{\omega}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ in uniform topology?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not connected: define an equivalence relation on it by $x\sim y$ iff $\sup_n|x_n-y_n|$ is finite. The equivalence classes are all open, and hence the set of bounded sequences is both open and closed.
The power $(0,1)^\omega$ is connected, even path-connected: given $x$ and $y$ the map $t\mapsto x+t(y-x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much !